# Cannot uncheck the checkbox with jquery prop()

Tags: jquery, checkbox

I have a simple cod, and I don't know why it is not working. When I click on the button, I want to uncheck the checkbox. I was trying with prop(), I was trying with attr(), and still nothing.

Maybe someone here can see the mistake?

HTML

```
<label>
  <input type="checkbox">
</label>

<button>CLICK</button>
```

jQuery

```
var btn = $("button");

    btn.on("click", function(){
    var checked = $(label).find("input").prop("checked");
        if (checked === true){
            $("checked").prop("checked", false);
        }
  })
```

https://jsfiddle.net/sm4a0d72/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use,

```
var btn = $("button");
btn.on("click", function() {
  $("label").find("input").prop("checked", false);
});
```

Problems in your code,

`label` should be wraped in `""`

You dont need to check if the element is already checked or not. You can directly uncheck it using `.prop("checked",false)`

[**Fiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/wwmyxp9o/12/)

Comment: yeap, it works :) thanks. but what's the difference?

Answer (score 0):

Your fiddle isn't working because there's no framework selected, `label` doesn't exist (you forgot the quotes) and "checked" is no DOM element.